# Table-driven lexers in Engineering a Compiler 2nd Edition

Tags: compilers

Recently, I am reading [Engineering a Compiler 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/012088478X).

But I am struggling to understand the following pseudocode.

[image]

Can anyone help me to explain the pseudocode in a simple and plain English?

- Why `NextChar` does take a char input?
- Why `lexeme` is the result 0f `lexeme + char`?
- What is the result of `Delta[state, cat];`?

Comment: This is why I don't like pseudocode. With real code, you could look up the meaning in some standard/documentation and/or play around with the code to see what it does. Furthermore, in examples like this, real code in, e.g., Python, would be just as concise and readable. At any rate, the behavior of `NextChar` isn't determined by this pseudocode. The authors have presumably described what it means in the text or just expect you to infer it from its name. The $\leftarrow$ stands for assignment, that line reassigns the variable `lexeme`. `δ[state,cat]` is an 2D array lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer your questions very quickly:

- `NextChar(char)` reads a character and assigns it to the variable `char`.
- The new character is appended to the current lexeme being built via the command `lexeme = lexeme + char`.
- The table `Delta` implements the transition function $\delta$ of a [DFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) (sometimes called an [FSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)). There is a lot of information on DFAs on the web and even on [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com).

I was able to answer these questions via a combination of common sense and a very rudimentary knowledge of how lexers work. More generally, when faced with code or pseudocode which you don't quite understand, you should try to figure out what the code is trying to accomplish, and how. For example, `NextChar` surely reads a character. You might expect it to return it, but from the context it is clear that it is actually stored in its argument. The fact that it is adjoined to `lexeme` significantly strengthens this guess.

Comment: Using a pass-by-reference parameter in pseudo code is evil...